# How to use Python `subprocess` to check status of external application on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, keepass

I'm having trouble determining the status of a Windows program ([KeePass](https://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/)) opened by the Python [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. Calling the KeePass program is straightforward, but once called, I can't seem to determine if it has been successfully opened or not.

I read up on the [`Popen.poll()`, `Popen.wait()` and `Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) objects and tested them out, but I can't seem to find a status to hook into.

**Example:** (see `# <--- What goes here to check status?` comment below)

```py
import subprocess as s
import os.path


keepass_app = 'C:\Program Files\KeePass Password Safe 2\KeePass.exe'
keepass_db = 'E:\Documents\test.kdbx'
pw_file = 'E:\\Documents\\test.md'


def check_each_pw(pw_file):
    
    for pw in pw_file:
        
        t = s.Popen([keepass_app, keepass_db, f'-pw:{pw}'], stdin=s.PIPE, stdout=s.PIPE, stderr=s.PIPE)
        
        if  : # <--- What goes here to check status?

            print(f'{pw} is not a valid password')
            t.terminate()

        else:
            print(f'{pw} is the correct password!')
            t.terminate()


check_each_pw(pw_file)
```

**EDIT1:**

Inserting into the above code, `output, errors = t.communicate()`, results in the same `b'' b''` for both `output` and `error` values.

```py
        t = s.Popen([keepass_app, keepass_db, f'-pw:{pw}'], stdin=s.PIPE, stdout=s.PIPE, stderr=s.PIPE)
        
        output, errors = t.communicate()
        
        if errors == b'':
            print(f'{pw} is the correct password!')
            print(output, errors)
            t.terminate()

        else:
            print(f'{pw} is not a valid password.!')
            print(output, errors)
            t.terminate()
```

**Results:**
The first line of `pw_file` is the wrong password. The KeePass database does not open; GUI shows the pop up:

[image]

...requiring manual intervention to close. The second line of `pw_file` is the correct password. KeePass opens successfully. But you can see that the terminal output for `t.communicate()` is the same for both attempts. Nothing to hook into.

```
PS E:\Documents\python\pw_program> python .\pw_prog.py
abc is the correct password!
b'' b''
test is the correct password!
b'' b''
```

Same thing goes for `t.wait()` (`0` instead of `b''` value, nothing to hook into):

```py
        t = s.Popen([keepass_app, keepass_db, f'-pw:{pw}'], stdin=s.PIPE, stdout=s.PIPE, stderr=s.PIPE)
        
        errors = t.wait()
        
        if errors == 0:
            print(f'{pw} is the correct password!')
            print(errors)
            t.terminate()

        else:
            print(f'{pw} is not a valid password.')
            print(errors)
            t.terminate()
```

```
PS E:\Documents\python\pw_program> python .\pw_prog.py
abc is the correct password!
0
test is the correct password!
0
```

And same thing goes for `t.poll()`:

```py
        t = s.Popen([keepass_app, keepass_db, f'-pw:{pw}'], stdin=s.PIPE, stdout=s.PIPE, stderr=s.PIPE)
        
        errors = t.poll()
        
        if errors is None:
            print(f'{pw} is the correct password!')
            print(errors)
            t.terminate()

        else:
            print(f'{pw} is not a valid password.')
            print(errors)
            t.terminate()
```

```
PS E:\Documents\python\pw_program> python .\pw_prog.py
abc is the correct password!
None
test is the correct password!
None
```

I also tried substituting `s.check_call` and `s.check_output`, no-go!

Answer (score 2):

use

```
output, errors = t.communicate()
```

To get logs in variables. Output will show the output logs and errors will show the error in case of crash.

You can also use `t.wait()` it will wait for the process to terminate and will return 0 in case of successful execution. In case of crash it will value other than 0.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work for KeePass (or I'm not sure how to correctly implement it!). See **EDIT1** in op.